# Relative positioned div inside of fixed parent

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-position

I need relative positioned div inside of fixed parent.

I have a website where everything is relative exept **fixed** popup window which opens on a button click. This popup window should be 100% width and 100% height, so it covers whole page.

Inside popup window I want **fixed** div on left side which is 60% width, and **relative** div on right side (40% width, auto height) which is available to scroll.

In fact, it's hard to explain so I made the fiddle. In this example, I want to scroll orange div instead of scrolling blue div. Is it possible to change scrollbar focus?

```
<div id='container'>
  <div id='inside-fixed-div'>
    <div id='left-fixed-container'></div>
    <div id='right-relative-container'>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/87x8dwn6/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To remove the scroll on the blue, I needed to remove the `1200px` height set on the `#container` and replace that value with 100%. The 100% height won't work unless the parent is also 100% height. Because of this, the parents needing this 100% height would be the document root and body.

```
html, body {
  margin: 0;
  height: 100%;
}

#container{
  ...
  height: 100%;
}
```

In addition, I set overflow to auto and height to 100% on `#right-relative-container`.

```
#right-relative-container{
  ...
  height: 100%;
  overflow: auto;
  ...
}
```

**Result** (quality of gif isn't great — apologies)

[image]

**Demo**
http://codepen.io/antibland/pen/eZjxom

Comment: Just curious what software are you using to record that on your Mac? (I use Techsmith Snagit on my Chromebook, but I'd like to know what you're using because the quality is better)

Comment: Thanks. I like it! ( and it's under the GPL too :D )

Comment: This is great! Thank you :D